# moving a View from Random x and y positions to specific X and Y positions with animations

Tags: android, animation, imageview, move, translate-animation

I hava a imageview. I put on specific position(specific x and y) on my constraint layout. I want to move(fly with animation) this imageview from random x y positions(for example out of screen) to specific positions that i put before on constraint layout.

I have tried translate animation. it didn't work.

```
{imageView4.animate().yBy(-200).y(imageView4.getY()).xBy(-200).x(imageView4.getX()).setDuration(4000);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `yBy(value)` allow you to move element to `value` relatively from current coordinate. Method `y(value)` allow you to move element to abslute `value` coordinate. So you need write this code:

```
imageView4.setX(startValueX);
imageView4.setY(startValueY);
imageView4.animate().x(endValueX).y(endValueY).setDuration(4000);
```

Notice that values given in pixels. If you need dp you have to convert px in dp.